# How to show command history with executed time on Unix

Tags: unix, bash, history

I tried export `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%D %T'` but it seems the time stamp of commands executed before I set HISTTIMEFORMAT will be the time I logged in current session. Is this normal? Is there any way to check when did the previous command executed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. If `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is set then the times are stored in history. If they're not stored then it has nothing to go on except the start time of the current shell.

Comment: Well done on the 10k :)